# Cake PHP Where Clause

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to learn CakePHP and I have a simple question,

I have

`$this->set('settings', $this->Setting->find('all'));`

in a Controller. I want to concentrate this down to:

`find all` settings `where` the type is equal to `General`

How could I do this?

Comment: All you need to know: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **findAllBy** function.

> findAllBy(string $value, array $fields, array $order, int
>   $limit, int $page, int $recursive)
>   You can read this in the [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

So your example will look like this:

```
$this->Setting->findAllByType('General');
$this->Setting->findAllByType($variable);    //If you want to use a variable
```

Or

```
$this->Setting->find('all', array('conditions' => array('type' => $type)));
```

Or **(NOT Recommended)**

```
$this->Setting->query("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE type = 'General';");
```

Comment: Oke no problem, happy to help!

Comment: -1 for suggesting the use of query. findAllBy is an appropriate answer (though using find all with conditions is _more_ appropriate as a general answer). Suggesting to use query however is not really appropriate - especially bearing in mind this question is by/for very new users. What's the point in using cakephp, if you're not going to "use" cakephp?

Comment: Thats for people that uses cakephp but want to use query instead of `findAllBy`, it can be easier for people. But fair vote, people need to use findAllBy instead of the query (updated)

Comment: Downvote removed it'd be better phrased as: "you can simply use `find('all', array('conditions' => array('type' => $type)));` OR `findAllByType($type)` - both of which will perform a find restricting by type. The first is generally more flexible (it's easier to add more conditions, or to have dynamic conditions). Lastly, you could if you really want to use query - but this removes  almost all of the benefits of using cake and for the example shown is not recommended `$result = $model->query($rawsql)`". Personally I wouldn't mention query at all - it's likely to be abused in ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you may still able to use `find` method of your model object by supplying it with parameters.

```
$settings = $this->Setting->find('all', array('conditions' => array('type' => 'General')));
$this->set('settings', $settings);
```

The most important thing for you as a beginner, regarding this question, is to check out **[this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find)**.